# Read epub book purchased from iTunes on Windows

Tags: itunes, books, epub

I have purchased a book through iTunes, it is formatted as an epub. Is there anyway I can read it in a Windows PC?

Comment: 2017 Update – It has been hard to find a definitive answer on the Apple Site to the following question.  Can I view DRM iBooks on my Windows PC using officially supported viewers?  It is frustrating that I buy all my DRM music and DRM Movies from iTunes but I cannot tell if I could buy DRM iBooks and view them on My PC.  Apple parses their official words carefully on their site to leave this subject ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on whether it's protected by DRM or not. If it's not DRM protected, you can use free software like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows). You can also read the ePub books in Firefox using the [EPUBReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/) extension and in Chrome using the [MagicScroll eBook Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magicscroll-ebook-reader/ghgnmgfdoiplfmhgghbmlphanpfmjble?hl=en) extension.

To know [if your eBook is DRM protected](http://www.technologytell.com/apple/60234/how-to-figure-out-which-of-your-ebooks-have-drm/) (fixed the description to correctly say "DRM" instead of "copyright"):

> 1. Open iTunes.
> 2. Select the target ebook.
> 3. Choose File.
> 4. Choose Get Info.
> 5. Look at the “Media Kind” field.
>
>    - If it says “book,” it is a web download.
>    - If it says “purchased book,” it’s a DRM free iBook purchase/download.
>    - If it says “protected book,” it has a DRM attached.

Comment: just checked, it is protected book

Comment: Then you need a platform on which Apple's iBooks app is present - either an iOS device (at present) or OS X 10.9 Mavericks (which is yet to be released). There is no other legal way of reading the book elsewhere.

Comment: Can I use Calibre to view books https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2510403?start=15&tstart=0   "Use the connect/share button in Calibre to connect to iTunes which will allow you to:
 "

Comment: Only for books that do not have DRM on them. Calibre will not help for iBooks eBooks that have DRM.

Answer (score 1):

To read ebooks on a PC, it's best buy them from one of the stores which provides a free ereader app for that platform, probably Kindle, Nook, Kobo, Googlebooks, or Sony.

There is no indication Apple will join that group (it took 3 years to extend iBooks from iOS to OS X), but there are some publishers, like O'Reilly, who sell unprotected books on the iBookstore, and these can be read on a PC with the apps described by M K.

Answer (score 1):

You can open your epub files with any of these programs:

- EPUB Reader
- [Adobe Digital Editions Home](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions/download.html) (recommended)
- [Okular](http://okular.kde.org)

You can read which one is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows7 machine I right-clicked the ibook in the iTunes application window and COPIED it via the pop-up menu onto my Windows desktop (you could copy it into any folder of your choosing). I then changed the extension of the copied file, which is a .ibooks-file, to .epub (just simply renaming the extension of the file name). I then could open the renamed file with the Calibre E-book viewer as well as with Adobe Digital Editions. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

In order to read Ibooks in your computer, you need to install the Adobe Digital Editions software (free). In ITunes, I right click on the book that I want to read then right click and paste it on my desktop. It will be paste with an epub extension. then I use the Adobe Digital Editions to open it. I have read a lot of books using this software with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ePUb files bought from iTunes are DRM protected, no open source readers could let you read the books. Because you have to remove the DRM protection first, and then you could [view the epub ibooks on pc](http://drm-remover.com/how-to-read-ibooks-on-pc/). And the most powerful free Requiem could do this work, but it will cost a lot of time.And it the best one could do the work.
One thing should remind is that this can only use it for personal, not commercial.