# Knowing the format and the protection of a book in iBooks

Tags: ios, books, ipad

I bought a book on the iBooks Store. Is there any way to know what format it is and what protection if any it has? (PDF/EPUB, type of DRM, etc.)

I use an iPad 3 with iBooks version 3.2 (last update: 2013.11.14).

Comment: What is the actual question you are looking to solve? How are you intending to interact with a book that's on the iPad?

Comment: @bmike The eventual question is "How can I export a book from iBooks on iPad to Windows 7 while keeping all highlightings". But I first wanted to know what the format of the book was to be able to ask a more accurate question.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104544/read-epub-book-purchased-from-itunes-on-windows

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Thanks, how to know if the book is epub or PDF, how to know if it has DRM and does the solutions in the link keep highlights?

Comment: The linked question answers your initial question. It describes how to use iTunes to find out the format of the book and whether it is DRM protected. It doesn't answer the additional question you asked in the comment about highlights, sorry.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Thanks, but the solution seems to use Max OSX. Is there any way to do it on iPad? When I go to the iTunes store on iPad, I don't see any purchased book. When I go to the iBooks store on iPad, I see purchased book but no option to see format or DRM.

Comment: Sorry I don't think there is a way to check the format on your iPad itself.

Comment: Some books in the iBookstore are in .ibooks format. You can tell these because the Requirements section indicates they can be read on an iPad but not on an iPhone.  Books in this format cannot be read on Windows even if they have no DRM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) to find out the format of the books on your iPad.

- Install iTunes on your Windows PC.
- Plug your iPad in to your Windows PC, iTunes should detect it and a button should appear in the top right of the iTunes window just under "Search Library". Click on the button for your iPad.
- You should be presented with a long horizontal list of options including "Summary", "Info", "Apps", etc. Click on the last option called "On This iPad".
- You should then see a list of options down the left called "Music", "Films", "TV Programmes", etc. Click on Books.
- Now you should have a list of your books in the centre of the iTunes window. Right-click on the book you want to know the format of and select "Get Info".

The window that appears will tell you the "Kind" of book it is. If I remember correctly they are "Protected book" for IBA or EPUB books with DRM, "Puchased book" for IBA or EPUB without DRM and "Book" for PDF files.